# Javascript stop working when I reaload page in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

The first time I start the app, localStorage works fine, but when I reload de browser I get this error. It also happens with alert("message") and some other JavaScript functions
[image]

```
componentWillMount(){
this.id=localStorage.getItem('id');
}
componentDidMount(){
if (!localStorage.getItem('id')) {
}
  else{
    this.loadData(this.id);
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code that you have tried? It would be much easier to answer your question if we saw an example of what you have tried

Comment: Also, [please upload code and error messages as text and not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1810460)

Comment: Your application is trying to read from `localStorage` in node, which doesn't exist. `localStorage` only exists in the browser.

Comment: componentWillMount(){
      this.id=localStorage.getItem('id');
}
componentDidMount(){
  if (!localStorage.getItem('id')) {
  }
  else{
    this.loadData(this.id);
  }

}

Comment: If you're doing server-side rendering then accessing `localStorage` in `componentWillMount` might throw an error on the server. It's usually safest the DOM in `componentDidMount`.